# Правильная обработка переносов в Markdown

Tags: php, javascript, markdown

Столкнулся с проблемой. Простейший сайт с текстовыми статьями, бэк на Phalcon PHP Framework (не суть), фронт ни на чём, отдельные JS наподобие jQuery и иже с ней. Нужно обеспечить поддержку Markdown. На фронте использую [simplemde](https://github.com/sparksuite/simplemde-markdown-editor), на бэке планирую [Parsedown](http://parsedown.org/). Вопрос основной в следующем - как правильно поступать с переносами? Parsedown преобразовывает, скажем так, двойной перенос в одиночный, одиночный перенос игнорирует. SimpleMDE, в свою очередь, видит перенос как перенос, одиночный, и адекватно его воспринимает. При выводе текста в форму (редактирование) приходится преобразовывать `\r\n` в `&#13;&#10;` чтобы переносы сохранились внутри `textarea`. Есть какие-то может быть общепринятые подходы в таких ситуациях? Сейчас я текст храню в базе "как есть", как он пришёл из формы. Всё форматирование и т.д. уже при выводе. Как правильно поступать с переносами?

---

Добавлено:

Вероятно, правильнее даже будет спросить совсем по-другому - есть ли какие-то библиотеки, поддерживающие и JS, и PHP, в том смысле, что, грубо говоря, какой текст юзер видит в превью редактора, такой он увидит и в готовой статье. Потому что тыкнуть лишний перенос (чтобы их стало два) совсем не трудно, при условии, что автор тут-же нажмёт кнопку Превью и увидит, что это привело к нужному результату.

А вообще очень долго не мог сформулировать вопрос, поскольку сталкиваюсь с такой задачей впервые и даже не знаю в какую сторону правильнее копать - обработка переносов, или универсализация парсинга на бэке и фронте, или вообще куда-то в другую сторону. Сюда-же можно отнести и вёрстку. Хорошо, пусть будет SimpleMDE, он построен на какой-то другой библиотеке, по-моему Marked, может как-то можно привыводе к отдельному например div'у применять Marked? Или какие-то стили из Marked.. То есть, за любые подсказки буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Не знаю, правильно или нет понял, но возможно вам нужна настройка `renderingConfig: {singleLineBreaks: ...}` тут https://github.com/sparksuite/simplemde-markdown-editor

Comment: Если вы сохраняете текст в базе "как есть", то Вам не нужно его преобразовывать, используйте simplemde.value(); для записи / чтения текста в/из редактора.

Comment: @RobertDampilon окей, НО: JS работает на фронте, с бэка идёт у нас типа подстановка в шаблон, да? что-то вроде `simplemde.value({{ $article->body }})` как-то по-моему во-первых кривовато, а во-вторых вообще никаких гарантий что всё правильно туда попадёт с учётом того, что сам  HTML переносы и пробелы кроппит. Я просто уже так пробовал :)

Comment: @Visman добавил в пост ещё подробностей

Comment: Как Вам вообще такое в голову пришло :) получайте запись по xhr и устанавливайте редактор, не выводите напрямую в шаблонизаторе. Если так не умеете, то выбрасывайте содержимое шаблона как то так: <script>window.sometext = {{ $article->body }}</script> и берите содержимое window.sometext уже в javascript. Но повторю, второй способ неправильный.

Comment: @RobertDampilon xhr умею, но как быть например с лентой? Если надо не в редактор выводить, а на страницу несколько статей

Comment: Используйте второй способ, попробуйте сделать сначала так, если получится, пробуйте сделать с xhr. Я не вижу ваш код, но думаю Вам будет сложнее сделать на xhr.